# How do I recover my RAID partition after the Ubuntu 11.04 upgrade?

Tags: raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover my RAID partition after the Ubuntu 11.04 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37514/how-do-i-recover-my-raid-partition-after-the-ubuntu-11-04-upgrade)

My RAID drive was working well with Ubuntu 10.10, but after doing an upgrade I am no longer able to mount my RAID drive. I think it is due to a invalid RAID description similar to this problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1503104

Thing is, I never had mdadm installed as far as I can tell. How do I change it back so that my system recognizes the RAID drive. The RAID drive is configured from some sort of software RAID on my motherboard I think.

blkid gives the output:

```
/dev/ramzswap0: TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda: TYPE="promise_fasttrack_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="a-UUID-number" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="another-UUID-number" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="another-UUID-number" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd: TYPE="promise_fasttrack_raid_member"
```

Any help is much a appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your RAID is configured on the motherboard and related to the information, that mdadm is'n installed (but i think it's installed, but you never used it?) so it looks like you are using the motherboards raid controller. That means you are useing an hardware RAID.

If this is the case, you should upgrade your RAID driver (modules) for the System/new kernel.

On the other Hand your posted output looks like there are 2 disk controlled by the mainboard RAID controller (sda & sdd).
How many disk are attached to your RAID Controller?

Because: if you are using an "hardware RAID" (configured on the mainboard/bios) so new kernel modules (driver) will be the solution (as i said).

If your RAID controller doen't build the RAID array and simply passed through the disk to the operating system, so you are using an software RAID (build by the ubuntu system). This could result in the problem with an invalid RAID description.

So first task: find out, what kind or RAID you are using.

Comment: Hello. When I search for mdadm in the Ubuntu Software Center it does show up as a program which I have not installed. In other words, I am given the option to install it. The RAID system used to work on my Windows / Ubuntu dual boot machine. I think the RAID system is set up through the motherboard as I have never dealt with any sort of RAID software whilst using an operating system.

Comment: If you are using the same RAID volume in windows and linux, so you have an hardware RAID owned by the motherboards RAID controller. Rebuild or reinstall the kernel modules could be a solution. What disk you are trying to mount and which error occurs?